# All my MediaWiki 1.20 pages are blank after upgrading to PHP 5.6.5

Tags: php, mediawiki

Server Team upgraded PHP version to latest 5.6.5. Now all pages are blank. Could you please guide me how to resolve this. MediaWiki Version: 1.20.2.
Thanks!

Comment: Make sure `error_reporting(~0)` is enabled at all times to fully debug the script, you may want to disable public access for that time. Also what was the previous PHP version? Read every single patch note and see what return values, flags, parameters and so on have changed, then look for those in your code.

Comment: Also, check your web server's error logs for error messages.  Somewhere you'll have a ton of messages getting dumped and that is what will help you solve this problem.

Comment: See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Errors_and_symptoms#You_see_a_Blank_Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue (blank page) is got resolved after upgrading MediaWiki from 1.20 to 1.24.1. As latest version of PHP (5.6.5) is not supporting the MediaWiki version (1.20).

Comment: You can accept your own answer, too. And this is what you should do to make us clear that it worked. Click on the pipe icon on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all I have to say that MediaWiki is an inflexible and somehow instable, bad core programmed script. But the issue could be solved with replacing the file in **/includes/MagicWords.php** with the new one, [download the corrected file here](http://uploadboy.com/3dasn7fxao1p.html#PHP_update_and_empty_pages_58219). Refer to my discussion on mediawiki support center: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Project:Support_desk#PHP_update_and_empty_pages_58219